# When can $p\to q$ be true while $p \wedge q$ be false?

Tags: logic

I know that the truth tables for both $p \to q$ and $p \wedge q$ are both different, but I cannot however figure out a statement that would make one true but the other false. If any would could help with this I would be very appreciative!

Comment: What is x, what is p, what is q...??

Comment: Try out every combination of x, p and q being true or false and see what the result is. There's only 8 ways.

Comment: What is this "x implies q and p and q both different"?

Comment: @Josh: I interpret your question as you wish to know about "the relation" between $p\rightarrow q$ and $p \wedge q$..?

Comment: @Lehs yes you are correct I just changed it

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636224/why-is-the-implication-p-rightarrow-q-false-if-and-only-if-p-is-true-and-q?rq=1) to verify the truth table for $p\to q$

Comment: It seems like Josh has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

When $P$ is false, $P\implies Q$ is true but $P\land Q$ is false.

Let $P$ be your favorite false proposition. $Q$ can be any proposition.

Answer (score 0):

One big difference between $p\rightarrow q$ and $p \wedge q$ is that the former always is true when $p$ is false, while the latter always is false when $p$ is false. These kind of formulas has one foot in human language and the other in algebra. Sometimes this is confusing for beginners.

An example then:

If it is easy to prove [my tautology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947270/can-hilbert-style-prove-my-tautology), then someone will do it.

It is easy to prove my tautology and someone will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Set $p = F$ and $q = T$. $p \Rightarrow q $ is therefore true in this instance, yet $p\wedge q$ would be false. Remember $(F \Rightarrow T) = T$, and $(F \wedge T) = F$, from the truth tables